# Using change scores of one variable to predict change scores of another variable

Tags: r, regression, inference, clinical-trials, pre-post-comparison

I have data from a pre-post RCT that considered multiple secondary outcomes of various types (e.g. psychological, diet-related, sleep-related). I want to know whether the magnitude of change in one of these types influences the magnitude of change in another type. For example, does the magnitude of change in sugar intake influence the magnitude of change in depression?

I thought to calculate a change score for the independent and dependent variable (i.e. post score - pre score) and use linear regression with adjustment for treatment group, for example in R:

```
model <- lm(depression_change_score ~ sugar_change_score + group_variable, data = df)
```

Does this seem to be a reasonable approach? I have been unable to find examples of this type of analysis being performed, which makes me hesitant that it is correct.